# version number is getting empty in flutter app

Tags: flutter

I am displaying the version of my app in the settings screen, To get the version number I am using the package_info package, when I run the app for first time, Version number is getting displayed properly but later once I clicked on other pages, and back to settings the version number is empty,

Below is my code, have a look at it and let me know where did I made the mistake

```
import 'package:package_info/package_info.dart';

class SettingsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsScreenState createState() => _SettingsScreenState();
}

class _SettingsScreenState extends State<SettingsScreen> {
  String appName;
  String version = "";
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getVersion();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double maxHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: maxHeight * 0.58),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.info,
                              size: 20.0,
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 3),
                              child: Text(
                                "version - " + version,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                  fontSize: ScreenUtil(allowFontScaling: true)
                                      .setSp(34),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Future getVersion() async {
    PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((PackageInfo packageInfo) {
      appName = packageInfo.appName;
      version = packageInfo.version;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Add widgetsBinding to run your code after build is completed

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.addPostFrameCallback(() {
    //executes after build is done
      getVersion();
    })
  }
```

2- Add setState inside getVersion method to rebuild your widget

```dart
 Future getVersion() async {
    PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((PackageInfo packageInfo) {
      setState(() {      
         appName = packageInfo.appName;
         version = packageInfo.version;
      });
    });
  }
```

I hope this is useful for you

Comment: small change ,  WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => getVersion()); it worked! Thanks